# login to website with python requests failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests

I'm trying to access https://instacart.com/store/wegmans/storefront for web scraping, but when I try to log in with Python's requests using this code:

```
from requests import session
url = 'https://www.instacart.com'
payload = {
    'action': 'submit',
    'email': 'my_email@gmail.com',
    'password': 'my_password'
}

with session() as c:
    c.post(url, data=payload)
    response = c.get('https://instacart.com/store/wegmans/storefront')
    print(response.headers)
    print(response.text)
```

I get "Very sorry." as response.text, and the following as response.headers:

```
{'Date': 'Tue, 02 Jul 2019 02:58:57 GMT', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'nginx', 'Set-Cookie': 'build_sha=8f3eb623f91516ad5369c4c373e577ec406c0fa1;Path=/;', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'X-Request-Id': 'a13241fe-fdce-4eb5-bfa2-958118c7690c', 'X-Runtime': '0.007429', 'Vary': 'Origin'}
```

I don't know what any of this means, but I'm guessing "Very sorry." is the automated response for when it doesn't recognize your POST request.  The password and email work when I login manually, and I assume the `'action':'submit'` part is right, because inspecting the login button says it's type="submit".

I am wondering if this has anything to do with the fact that instacart.com doesn't have a url that directs you to a login page.  the homepage has a login form, but you have to click "Already have an account? Log in" before it will pop up.  Is this the problem or is something wrong with my code?

Comment: I couldn't login using requests module, but here are my findings. Login url: https://www.instacart.com/accounts/login, payload: {"user": {"email": "my_email", "password": "my_password"}, "authenticity_token": "csrf_token"}. Anyway I suggest you to use selenium, because this website is JavaScript heavy.

Comment: out of curiosity, how did you find out it needs an authenticity_token?  also, if I were to add that to my payload, does the string "csrf_token" work or do I need to get the actual token from somewhere?

Comment: In Chrome DevTools (Network panel) when you click on login button, there is a POST request with those values. You need to get the actual token from <meta name="csrf_token"> or in hidden field of login form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for login:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}

session = requests.Session()

res1 = session.get('http://www.instacart.com', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res1.content, 'html.parser')
token = soup.find('meta', {'name': 'csrf-token'}).get('content')
data = {"user": {"email": "your_email", "password": "your_password"},
        "authenticity_token": token}
res2 = session.post('https://www.instacart.com/accounts/login', headers=headers, data=data)
print(res2)
res3 = session.get('https://instacart.com/store/wegmans/storefront', headers=headers)
print(res3)
session.close()
```

As @andreilozhkin commented, from Chrome DevTools, you can see exactly what payload is passed to POST request, which includes 'authentacity_token'. I got that token by first making a GET request to `http://www.instacart.com` and used it in PUT request to Login.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I substituted "your_email" and "your_password" for my email and password and got a 404, and a 403 when I ran this code.  Is there something I'm missing?  Did you get a 200 code for res2 and res3?

Comment: @user3150635, sorry I pasted some other code I was trying. I have updated the answer. Please try now.

Comment: I just tried this and am getting the 401 or 403 code. Does this still work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer by Kamal will no longer work. If you look at the POST request, in addition to the email, password, and authenticity_token- there is another field named captcha.

I believe this is an invisible google recaptcha field. The login page does load google's recaptcha library(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js) but there is no *g-recaptcha* class field that you would normally expect. I'm not sure how to obtain the captcha token.

However, another way to bypass the login entirely is to use the library browser_cookies3. You can then login using your browser and load your cookies when making the request.

```
import requests
import browser_cookie3

# make sure to login to instacart.com before running this script
cookies = browser_cookie3.chrome(domain_name='instacart.com')

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.193 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://www.instacart.com/v3/retailers'  # example endpoint that requires authentication

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```